# Why won't chfn allow non-ascii chars or equal signs?

Tags: linux, users, ascii

I'm wondering what the historical purpose is of designing chfn command to warn people over the use of non-ASCII symbols, (and why only enforce it for phone numbers?) Is this something that still applies to all unix systems, only some, or is it just historical?

Also, the chfn man page on Debian says that equal signs and commas can only be placed in the last field. The comma part makes sense, as it's used to separate the fields, but does the equal sign have some similar use?
Again, I don't know if this is something that is version specific, historical, or universal.

Comment: There are several systems which provide `chfn`, e.g., [AIX](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixuseradmin/), and without limiting the question, only opinions are likely be offered.

Comment: I didn't limit the question because I wasn't sure if it was universal to unix, version specific, or if it was just a historical thing. Should I create different questions for each possiblilty?

Comment: I'm not sure - your comment about the existing use on AIX would be helpful to factor in, but there's a lot of unknowns in the history...

Answer (score 2):

The command (with different restrictions) is provided on different platforms.  According to [HPUX's manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chfn&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=HP-UX%2011.22&arch=default&format=html), the command originated with BSD (and there was a [SunOS4 manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chfn&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS%204.1.3&arch=default&format=html) for it — none for Solaris).

The [AIX documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixuseradmin/) shows the restriction, but comparing [`useradd`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/useradd.htm) and [`chfn`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/chfn.htm) manual pages, that refers to the *user name* rather than *full name*.

The same restriction is found in the [oldest version](https://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/pkg-shadow/upstream/trunk/src/chfn.c?revision=1224&view=markup) of shadow-utils which you may be using with some Linux variations.  Based on the copyright dates, that *might* be from 1994 (the *RCS identifier* says July 1999).  Following comments about the author:

- [The Source Fantastic: The Shadow Suite](https://ef.gy/tsf-1-shadow)
- [Julianne Frances Haugh](https://web.archive.org/web/19970701225954/http://www.tab.com/~jfh/) (archived web page)

  > I came to work at IBM/Austin in May, 1989 as a contractor working on software security for AIX v3.1. Between 1989 and 1995 I worked on a number of IBM operating systems, including AIX PS/2, AIX S/370 and OS/400 V2R3. Quite the checkered path. I finally accepted a full-time position with IBM and left the AIX Change Team in June, 1995. My initial responsibilities as an OS/2 developer were looking into POSIX solutions for OS/2. Eventually I moved to the filesystem development group and there I worked until my development assignment was completed in October, 1996.
- [chfn - change user name and information](http://www.fifi.org/cgi-bin/man2html/usr/share/man/man1/chfn.1.gz)

leads to the conclusion that there was some influence on its design by the author's work with AIX.

Now - why AIX did this is hard to say, but likely to make scripting simpler (and because there was no good reason for people to have equals-signs in their *full name*, any more than the *user name* would).

Comment: Interesting. The use of the equal sign has a specific meaning in the /etc/security/password and /usr/lib/secirity files in AIX. The restrictions on usernames and groupnames with useradd and groupadd are distro dependant, I thought the same would be true for chfn.

Comment: It probably depends upon which branch of the code is used - I was looking at Debian, but it's not unusual for it to differ from Red Hat or SuSE.

Comment: User names have different reasons to be restricted than full names.  Restrictions on user names are mostly related to security, and to being able to support legacy syntax for various utilities, f.i. once upon a time `chown user:group ...` was written `chown user.group ...`.

Comment: Sure, but unless you can point to [SMIT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-smit/index.html) internals, that's a moot point.

Comment: Legacy syntax is not necessarily still documented, but it's kept around for ever and ever with all its quirks, "in order not to break old scripts". _shrug_